# purpose of background dataset for shap library deep explainer?

Tags: python, deep-learning, shap

I was going through a tutorial for [Deep Learning Model Interpretation Using SHAP](https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-learning-model-interpretation-using-shap-a21786e91d16) when I came across this code block:

```
# select backgroud for shap
background = x_train[np.random.choice(x_train.shape[0], 1000, replace=False)]

# DeepExplainer to explain predictions of the model
explainer = shap.DeepExplainer(model, background)

# compute shap values
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(x_test_each_class)
```

What is the purpose of this background dataset?

Comment: Background is training dataset for the SHAP exercise.  You set background sample as your trained model which you then use to pass your data point(s) of interest to pass through and average for missing features. You'll change background and you may get different Shapley values

Comment: Can you elaborate on the sentence "you set background sample as your trained model"? I thought the `model` variable already held all the information for my trained model. Why does SHAP need the background dataset to train again?

Comment: You don't retrain model. You use background dataset to learn Shapley values the SHAP way.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a scenario involving four features: A, B, C, and D.

For an individual i, their respective feature values are 4, 6, 7, and -1.

In the context of calculating the "average marginal contribution" of the C feature when it is introduced to a combination of features A and B for individual i (a key step in calculating the Shapley value), the following procedure is employed:

1. Maintain the values of features A, B, and C fixed for individual "i" (A = 4, B = 6, C = 7).
2. Create an artificial individual j, who has equal values of A and B as individual i.
3. Randomly select a `donor`.
4. Utilize the `donor`'s value of feature D as the value for feature D of both individual i and j (e.g. `donor` has a D value of 3).
5. Use the `donor`'s value of feature C as the value for feature C of individual j (e,g.`donor` has a C value of 9).

Ultimately, calculate the disparity between:

a. For individual "i": f(A = 4, B = 5, C = 7, D = 3)

b. For individual "j": f(A = 4, B = 5, C = 9, D = 3)

Repeat the steps from 2 to 5 iteratively. This iterative process effectively mitigates the effects of feature D, allowing the determination of the isolated influence of feature C while assuming A = 4 and B = 5.

These `donors` are randomly drawn from backgroud distribution.

Answer (score 0):

To get SHAP values, we need to compute the difference between two expectations (ref. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.07874.pdf - equations (8) and (9)).

We cannot compute these expectations analytically and, thus, use Monte-Carlo estimates. Background dataset is used to generate samples which are used to calculate these estimates.

And, of course, if the background dataset changes, the estimates would change and thus SHAP values would change.